# Why does one of my monitors turns off (sleep) when I switch to fullscreen on Flash (Youtube,...)?

Tags: display, flash, nvidia-graphics-card, youtube

I just got a new monitor (kept the old one as extended desktop).

Whenever I switch to (or from) fullscreen mode on a youtube video on the new monitor (which is the main one), it turns off for 2-3 seconds, even the backlight. Kinda like when you change resolution. If I move the same window to the other monitor and try there, I don't have this problem.
It's not specific to Youtube, I have the same problem on Dailymotion for example, but not Twitch for some reason.

If I turn off Hardware Acceleration in flash settings the problem goes away but I'm not sure that's a good idea (any downside to having it off?)...

Using Windows 7 professional 64bits, Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m and Flash version 11,8,800,94. Tried with IE9 and the problem is there too. The monitor with the problem is an Asus VG23AH.

Edit: The screen also turns off for a second if I try to skip forward to a unbuffered part of the video while in fullscreen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Nvidia Control Panel, "Adjust desktop color settings" tab, there's a "**Content type reported to the display**" option.

It was on autoselect, and if I leave it like that it switch from (not sure I have the right translation from there, I have it in french) "Desktop programs" to "Fullscreen videos" when I switch to fullscreen on youtube, which make the screen turn off for a second. Setting it manually fix the problem.

Only thing I don't know is which option to choose. I set it to **Fullscreen videos** for now. Anyone have a recommandation?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, because I think the settings page changed and I can't find this option myself. Turn on g-sync, then turn it off. That fixed it for me.

Comment: This isn't a solution to the posted question, G-Sync wasn't around when this question was first asked. This answer would be better as a comment.